# Android - ExpandableListView - load Image in getChildView()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have a problem with the amount of calls of the "getChildView" method.

In my getChildView() method i load per child a image from a server and put it into a ImageView.

The business-logic of "loading a image" is written in a separate AsyncTask.

My problem is, that the method "getChildView" is called more then the number of the childs.

This is quite bad, because the AsyncTask is called as often the method is called ... so i have a performance problem.

Maybe my approach isnt really good ... if someone could tell me a better solution, to not hold the main thread, it would be great. :)

PS: The class "boBilder" loads the images and puts it in the imageview.

Here is my code:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;

    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.zeile_custom, null);

    Log.d("pictures", "--- > getChildView");

    final TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtMeldungTitel);
    final TextView erstelltAm = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtEstelltAm);

    final ImageView imgNachricht = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    ProgressBar progess = (ProgressBar) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.progressBar_Zeile);

    boBilder boBilder = new boBilder();

    TextView txtdatum_Erstellung = (TextView) vi
            .findViewById(R.id.txtNachricht_Datum);

    HashMap<String, String> nachricht = new HashMap<String, String>();    
    nachricht = this.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    // // Wenn noch nicht gelesen, dann anpassen
    if (nachricht.get("gelesen").equalsIgnoreCase("J")) {

        vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));

    } else {
        vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        erstelltAm.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
    }

    title.setText(nachricht.get("titel"));    
    erstelltAm.setText(nachricht.get("bezeichnung"));
    txtdatum_Erstellung.setText(nachricht.get("datum_erstellung")
            .substring(0, 10));

    if (!nachricht.get("bild1").equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        boBilder.pruefeBildVorhanden_Liste(nachricht.get("bild1"),
                true, 1, this.activity, imgNachricht, progess, this,
                groupPosition, childPosition);
    }

    return vi;
}
```

And here is the code of "boBilder":

```
public boolean pruefeBildVorhanden_Liste(String nameBild,
            boolean herunterladenWennFehlt, int nummerBild, Activity activity,
            ImageView imgView, ProgressBar progress,
            ListenAdapter listenAdapter, Integer group, Integer child) {

        AsyncTaskFTPConnection ftpConnection = new AsyncTaskFTPConnection();

        ftpConnection.setActivity(activity);
        ftpConnection.setImageView(imgView);
        ftpConnection.setAdapter(listenAdapter);
        ftpConnection.setProgressBar(progress);
        ftpConnection.setSuchBild(nameBild, nummerBild);
        ftpConnection.groupPosition = group;
        ftpConnection.childPosition = child;
        ftpConnection.execute("");

        return true;
    }

    public class AsyncTaskFTPConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        public DatenTransferFTPServer ftpConn;

        private Nachricht_Detail activity = null;

        private Activity act = null;
        private ImageView imgView = null;
        private ProgressBar progress = null;

        public Integer groupPosition;
        public Integer childPosition;

        private ListenAdapter adapter = null;

        private String cSuchBild;
        private int nummerBild;

        public void setActivity(Nachricht_Detail fenster) {
            if (fenster != null) {
                this.activity = fenster;
            }
        }

        public void setActivity(Activity fenster) {
            if (fenster != null) {
                this.act = fenster;
            }
        }

        public void setImageView(ImageView imgView) {
            this.imgView = imgView;
        }

        public void setProgressBar(ProgressBar progress) {
            this.progress = progress;
        }

        public void setAdapter(ListenAdapter adapter) {
            this.adapter = adapter;
        }

        public void setSuchBild(String cName, int nummerBild) {
            this.cSuchBild = cName;
            this.nummerBild = nummerBild;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            if (this.activity != null) {
                this.ftpConn = new DatenTransferFTPServer("", "", "",
                        this.activity);
            } else {
                this.ftpConn = new DatenTransferFTPServer("", "", "", this.act);
            }

            String returnString = "";

            File bild = null;

            if (this.activity != null) {
                bild = new File(Pfade.gebenPfad(this.activity,
                        Pfade.PfadeSammlung.LOKAL_BILDER_ORDNER)
                        + this.cSuchBild);
            } else {
                bild = new File(Pfade.gebenPfad(this.act,
                        Pfade.PfadeSammlung.LOKAL_BILDER_ORDNER)
                        + this.cSuchBild);
            }

            if (!bild.exists()) {

                if (this.ftpConn.StatusVerbindung) {

                    // Picture is not downloaded yet ..


                    if (this.activity != null) {
                        if (this.ftpConn.downloadDatei(
                                Pfade.gebenPfad(this.activity,
                                        Pfade.PfadeSammlung.FTP_BILDER_ORDNER)
                                        + this.cSuchBild, bild.getPath())) {
                            returnString = "erfolg";
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (this.ftpConn.downloadDatei(
                                Pfade.gebenPfad(this.act,
                                        Pfade.PfadeSammlung.FTP_BILDER_ORDNER)
                                        + this.cSuchBild, bild.getPath())) {
                            returnString = "erfolg";
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    // No connection
                    returnString = "keineVerbindung";
                }

            } else {

                // Picture is already downloaded ...
                returnString = "erfolg";

            }

            return returnString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("erfolg")) {

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

                Bitmap bitmap;
                try {
                    if (this.activity != null) {
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory
                                .decodeStream(
                                        new FileInputStream(
                                                Pfade.gebenPfad(
                                                        this.activity,
                                                        Pfade.PfadeSammlung.LOKAL_BILDER_ORDNER)
                                                        + this.cSuchBild),
                                        null, options);

                        ((Nachricht_Detail) this.activity).zeigeBild(bitmap,
                                this.nummerBild);
                    } else {
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory
                                .decodeStream(
                                        new FileInputStream(
                                                Pfade.gebenPfad(
                                                        this.act,
                                                        Pfade.PfadeSammlung.LOKAL_BILDER_ORDNER)
                                                        + this.cSuchBild),
                                        null, options);

                        this.imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        Log.d("pictures", "Set pic!");

                        this.progress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    this.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_nachricht);
                    this.progress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                }

            } else {
                // Error ... set default pic
                this.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_nachricht);
                this.progress.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I recommend you to try Universal-Image-Loader instead of boBilder.

Comment: This is my own  class ... there is not much code. Just load an image from a application server. Cant imagine, that is the problem?

Comment: It would be great if you could give us the code of boBilder, so we could see if the problem is in this class, maybe this is the reason of the poor performance.